# Blender 2.8. Export material

Tags: materials, export, import, shaders

I made this water material and I was wondering how to export this material to use in other projects. Haven't find a concrete answer to this for some reason.[image]

Comment: Do you want to export it to other projects within blender or other projects in a different piece of software?

Comment: In Blender, you don't export and import materials (or any other type of object). You either [link or append](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/linked_libraries.html) them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaders are implementation specific, and there are no real standards as to how to process, store, or describe them.  Blender uses a variant of OSL for cycles, and a slightly different version for EEVEE.  Unity uses DirectX (HLSL) and OpenGL (OGLSL) shaders (based on the target platform), Unreal can do something similar.  Substance uses a proprietary format for their PBR shading.

Occasionally, if two tools are widely used, the parties involved will make a bridge between the two.  However, without knowing what you are trying to export *to*, we cannot give much advice.